# Java android get File from mounted storage

Tags: android

I want to read file in android apk , I connected a usb storage to my device and I want to read file which I have inside my pendrive of whole device it works this ;

```
private synchronized File getFileWithLocomitiveDump() {
    Map<String, File> externalLocations = ExternalStorage.getAllStorageLocations();

    File externalSdCard = externalLocations.get(ExternalStorage.EXTERNAL_SD_CARD);
    if (externalSdCard.exists() && externalSdCard.listFiles() != null) {
        for (File f : externalSdCard.listFiles()) {
            if ("NumberStation_DUMP.xml".equalsIgnoreCase(f.getName())) {
                String path = f.getPath().replace("_DUMP.xml", ".xml");
                File file11 = new File(path);
                if (file11.exists()) {
                    file11.delete();
                }
                moveFile(file11, f);
                return f;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

But on one device my application does not see this file. I download a Terminal Emulator and I see that a file is here :

```
    /mnt/media_rw/6CAA-15ED

"usb://1049/UsbStorage"
```

I try do this :

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls /mnt/media_rw/6CAA-15ED");
```

But I get a permission denied. I download a
ES File Explorer File Manager and if I granded a usb connection I see this file. Waht I should to do , to read this files ?

and this is my path : usb://1006/UsbStorage

Comment: the path's of pen drive connected through OTG are  different in all devices. So if you put static path according to your device so it will creating error on other devices

Comment: @VipulChauhan so what I have to do ?

Comment: i already ask the same question buddy but don't get any answer for otg upmark the question if you like it

Comment: @VipulChauhan so you do not have idea what to do ?

Comment: yes you are right. I don't know for otg but i Know for external sd card which is shown in given link

Comment: @VipulChauhan could you give me this link ?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html read this link i think you get your answer

Comment: @VipulChauhan so you use this :  getExternalFilesDirs() and getExternalCacheDirs() ?

Comment: @VipulChauhan could you give me some example ?